# Application properties is being read twice when using spring cloud config server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have recently upgraded springboot from 2.7.x to 3.1.x in our project and noticed something peculiar. When looking at the properties resolved using the `/actuator/env` endpoint, I noticed that the application.properties file is being read twice.

This is the relevant portion of /actuator/env response.

```
{
    "name": "applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]",
    "properties": {
        ...
    }
},
{
    "name": "configserver:ssh://config-server-host/application.properties",
    "properties": {
       ...
    }
},
{
    "name": "Config resource 'class path resource [application.properties]' via location 'optional:classpath:/'",
    "properties": {
                ...
    }
}
```

Normally I would expect the properties defined in the file deployed on cloud config server to take precedence but since the application.properties is showing up first in the list with the source as `applicationConfig`, those values are taking effect.

This seems to be new in 3.1. In the `/actuator/env` response when using Spring boot 2.7.x, I see only two entries with `configserver` one being the first one.

Why is the application.properties on my classpath being loaded twice? Once as applicationConfig and later as config resource?